# Can't match variable from FORM with MYSQL record in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening,

I have a problem with my login code. I've created form that I take variables from into my php code(that part works well). Then I created php login code where I'm trying to match password by entered login. But even when I enter login and the right password I still get `else` . Here is the code:

```
<?php

$login=$_POST["loginas"];
$password=$_POST["passwordas"];

//connect to mysql
$rysys = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','testas');
//are we connected?
if($rysys->connect_error){
    die("Neprisijungeme, nes: " . $rysys->connect_error);
}

//the query
$sql = "SELECT password FROM vartotojai WHERE login='$login'";
$rezultatas=$rysys->query($sql);
if($password == $rezultatas){
    echo "Prisijungeme \n";
}
    else{
        echo "Neteisingas slaptazodis arba prisijungimo vardas\n";
    }


?>
```

Explanation:
`$login` I get it from my form
`$password` I get it from my form
I have database `'testas'`, that has `'vartotojai'` table. And `vartotojai` table has `'password'` and `'login'`
Login and password that I enter is 100% like in database.

Comment: If you're using mysqli use prepared statements, having a variable inside your query beats the whole idea :)
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Try to `var_dump(rezultatas)`

Comment: I'm just a beginner, can you explain me more what have I done wrong? :)

Comment: Well, use kind of mixed MySql and MySqli, since you're a beginner, go over a quick tutorial of MySqli before you start coding. If you encounter a problem like this in the future, always `var_dump` variables untill you find the culprit.

Comment: Condition should be `if($password == $rezultatas["password"]){`

Comment: @devpro don't encourage him, he needs to follow a tutorial, learn the whole thing and fix his code :)

Comment: @odedta u r right... But using password for condition not good.

Comment: @odedta , Yeah, I found my mistake :) but then other problem appears `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`

I'm learning like for only 5-7days... But I'm spending much time on it :)

Comment: @TomasVilemaitis no worries mate, I know it's not easy... i'm just trying to keep you on the right path. Good luck!

Comment: Don't worry about that.. I am also same like u in early days... Hard work never be lost... Good luck

Comment: Thanks for wishes guys! I found the solution on my own! :)

Comment: The way you are passing the `$_POST` variable into your query is vulnerable for sql injection. Use [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to pass on your values into the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on myself. I added one more line:

`$rez=$rezultatas->fetch_assoc();` Ths line helped me to create a assoc array from results I got from query.

`if($password == $rez["password"]` And here I just used assoc array to check if it's good.

@odedta , You're right. Finding answers to your problems on your own is more useful. But to get advices from people that are way better than me is good way to learn as well.

Answer (score 2):

The query function doesn't return your password field as a string, please read the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Your check will therefore always be false. Correct use of the function would be the following:

```
if($password == $rezultatas["password"]){
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: Tomas, read before you code please... for Objects you use $variable->property;